# UpdateProgress with an UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updateprogress

I want to show the `UpdateProgress` on page A when a user clicks on the "Next" button to go to next page. The next page is Page B, which has heavy data loading.

When the button is clicked, it doesn't show the `UpdateProgress`.

What's missing from this code, and how can it be made to show?

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="Server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate >
       Please wait ...
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
   <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnNext" EventName="Click" />
   </Triggers>                                    

   <ContentTemplate>                                          
      <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" TabIndex="1" Text="Cancel"onclick="btnCancel_Click" />                                    
      <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" TabIndex="2" Text="Next" onclick="btnNext_Click" />
   </ContentTemplate>                                 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `DisplayAfter` to a very small value to make the progress indicator appear immediately, e.g.:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="Server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" DisplayAfter="1">
```

Answer (score 5):

Couple of things to try:

1) Move the **UpdateProgress** control inside the UpdatePanel

2) Remove the **AssociatedUpdatePanelID** attribute from the **UpdateProgress** tag

I'm banking on Option 1 doing the trick.

**EDIT**

Here is a non-ProgressTemplate way, using client-side event handlers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler); 
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
     // some code to show image, e.g:
     document.getElementById('somedivwhichasimage').className = 'show';
}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
     // some code to hide image, e.g:
     document.getElementById('somedivwhichasimage').className = 'hidden';
}
</script>
```

Comment: is that code you posted exact? is there anything missing? there are other ways to do the progress (do it purely client-side with javascript). see my edit for another option.

Comment: Move the UpdateProgress control inside the UpdatePanel -> Worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add this code on the code behind of this page.

```
 protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
 }
```

Hope this helps!!

Edit:
Follow this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421.aspx

Adding the code from aspx page that I tried and is working,

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> </asp:ScriptManager>

   <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="Server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"> 
    <ProgressTemplate > 
     <asp:Label ID="lblwait" runat="server" Text="Please wait.."></asp:Label>
    </ProgressTemplate> 
</asp:UpdateProgress> 

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">  
   <Triggers> 
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" /> 
   </Triggers>                                     

   <ContentTemplate>                                           
      <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" TabIndex="1" Text="Cancel" />                                     
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" TabIndex="2" Text="Next" onclick="Button1_Click" /> 
   </ContentTemplate>                                  
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Somehow I cannot add the code, you may refer the link. Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

try putting `UpdateProgress` control inside `UpdatePanel`. and that should work for you.
hope that helps!